# SKSpriteNode with Image will not colorize

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have created an SKSpriteNode like so:

```
 //Easy Button Image

_easyImage = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"smiley.png"];
_easyImage.position = CGPointMake(-20,screenHeight / 2);
_easyImage.name = easyBtnName;
_easyImage.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
_easyImage.zPosition = 10;

[self addChild:_easyImage];
```

I'm trying to colorize the image after being clicked in the touches began method. I have a reference to the SKSpriteNode Property so once I see that it is clicked I execute this code

```
        SKAction *pulseRed = [self colorizeChoosenSpriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor]];
        [_easyImage runAction: pulseRed];
```

Which references this method

```
    -(SKAction*)colorizeChoosenSpriteNodeWithColor:(SKColor*)color
     {
SKAction *changeColorAction = [SKAction colorizeWithColor:color  colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.3];
SKAction *waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.2];
SKAction *selectAction = [SKAction sequence:@[changeColorAction, waitAction]];
return selectAction;
      }
```

However, the color of my image never changes. I can change the texture of the image completely but I can't just change the colorization.

EDIT: I removed some code that was distracting from the problem. I've debugged the code and it's definitely executing correctly, but I'm not getting the expected result.

Update: The color is appearing beneath my image I've discovered.

[image: Same code except one has a missing image. Red color shows on the Sprite Node with the missing image?]

The Picture on the Left is shown with a missing image, the picture on the right is using the correct image. The color is only appearing if the image is not displayed. How can I actually colorize the spriteNode Texture?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a for loop in the touches began method. Your touches began method should look like this:

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     for (UITouch *touch in touches) {   
     if ([node.name isEqualToString:easyBtnName]){
         _easyImage.color = [SKColor redColor];
         _easyImage.colorBlendFactor = 1;
         SKAction *pulseRed = [self colorizeChoosenSpriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor]];
    [_easyImage runAction: pulseRed];
    } }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to set color

```
func changeColor() -> UIColor{
  var color:UIColor
  switch (arc4random_uniform(6)) {
    case 0:
      color = UIColor.purpleColor()
    case 1:
      color = UIColor.blueColor()
    case 2:
      color = UIColor.yellowColor()
    case 3:
      color = UIColor.magentaColor()
    case 4:
      color = UIColor.greenColor()
    default:
      color = UIColor.redColor()
  }
  return color
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) 
{
  let colorAction = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(self.changeColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 1)
  SKSpriteNode.runAction(colorAction)
}
```

It worked for me. Good luck!